# Apache Ignite LINQ AND bitwise operators

Tags: c#, ignite

I have a LINQ query with bitwise AND operator:

```
cache.Where((c.Type & 2) == 2)
```

Because currently Ignite.LINQ doesn't support custom schema([How to change schema name on executing LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562948/how-to-change-schema-name-on-executing-linq-query)) name I use workaround to get SQL from LINQ query and replace schema name manually:

```
var cacheQueryable = cache
            .AsCacheQueryable()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToCacheQueryable()
            .GetFieldsQuery();
//replace schema name and execute plain SQL query
```

But LINQ expression with bitwise AND operator translates to SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients  as _T0 where (((_T0.Type and ?) = ?)
```

It seems that bitwise AND operator should translates to function BITAND (_T0.Type, ?). But instead it translates to simple AND operator. Is it an error?

Comment: Try `(c.Type ^ 2) == 0` for fun (`xor`). If I'm reading the source correctly, I'd expect you'd get a `NotSupportedException`. Because C# does not distinguish (on the node level) between bitwise and logical `and`, the provider would have to do it based on type, but it appears that it currently supports no bitwise operations at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is right, Ignite LINQ does not support bitwise operations

Comment: You can apply another silly workaround (for example, by signaling the bitwise operator with some crazy expression that you then textually replace again) or you could consider cobbling together a change for [`CacheQueryExpressionVisitor`](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Linq/Impl/CacheQueryExpressionVisitor.cs), which, as far as I can tell, shouldn't be too hard for minimal support. Basically, either translate to `and`/`or` if both sides are boolean and `bit_and`/`bit_or` otherwise (letting Ignite take care of any remaining type errors).